# iterating directly on collection, or using iterator

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, iterator

I have noticed I can do both, with same result

```
foo = """
  this is 
  a multi-line string.
"""

for line in foo.splitlines():
  pass

for line in iter(foo.splitlines())
  pass
```

What is the difference?
Which one should I prefer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `for` statement implicitly calls `iter()` on the object you try to iterate over. The second form then is just redundant, doing the same work twice with no benefit.

There *could* be an advantage to storing the `iter()` iterator *before* you loop:

```
foo_iter = iter(foo.splitlines())
for line in foo_iter:
    next_line = next(foo_iter, '')
    print(next_line.rstrip())
    print(line.rstrip())
```

Comment: In that situation I think it's preferable to use a while loop. A for loop implies iterating over each element individually to me. Though I suppose in this specific instance wrapping `foo.splitlines()` in a generator that yields a tuple of two elements per `next()` call would also work.

Comment: @Dunes: not sure that that is warranted. When parsing a file with a repeating record structure I often use nested `for` loops, iterating further over lines until the end-of-record is detected, for example. Using a `while` would make such code needlessly complicated.

Comment: you would get a stopIteration error running your code

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: you could, unless you give `next()` a default to return instead.

Comment: How does the for loop know when to stop iterating over a record? The condition to test for the end of the record has to be in the body of the for loop rather than the condition of the while loop. I believe in that situation the for loop adds more complexity. Compare "while parsing a record do ..." with "for each line in a file parse line as part of a record unless line is end of record".

Comment: @Dunes: Python doesn't have an `until` construct, so you'd have to use `while True:`, then at the end of the block test for the condition. In the loop you'd then have to handle the `StopIteration` exception that'll be raised when you reach the end of the file. Then there is the seeking to the start of a record to handle (just use `continue` if you are using a `for` loop). A nested `for` loop is far simpler.

Comment: Was looking for an example in my own code to show you what I meant, and I found I used the for loop technique. Oops. I wrote a toy program to show how I would write a while loop and a corresponding for loop. I don't really see much of a difference. http://ideone.com/mZnnaD

Comment: @Dunes: now add more processing into the loops. The `try` and `except` lines get further and further apart, making it harder to see what goes on.